# Hide subfolder url in all pages Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have installed the site in a subfolder of an existing site. When I open the home page, the url looks like this: www.nextarconsulting.com/SitoNextar/

I would like it to appear instead: www.nextarconsulting.com

I tried different solutions via .htacces but no one works!

PS: The old site (where I have the subfolder with the new wordpress installation) has the same url as the new site, so I have 2 equal link redirects after I modify the .htaccess of the new site. Can this be in conflict?

Here is my .htaccess file :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /SitoNextar/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /SitoNextar/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
# BEGIN Hotlinking

# END Hotlinking
```

I would also like to see that the other pages of the site no longer appear on the folder path. For example: www.nextarconsulting.com/SitoNextar/contacts.html must become
www.nextarconsulting.com/contacts.html

Comment: is your site still in the SitoNextar folder?

Comment: The site is in a previous wordpress installation. so inside the old installation I did a new installation inside the folder / SitoNextar /

Comment: Where is your current website?

Comment: Outside the subfolder /SitoNextar/

Comment: Is it in root or not, if it is in the root then change permalinks in backend.

Comment: I think so. It's in public_html. But how do I modify the permalinks? I'm new in wordpress and inexperienced

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)).  By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Answer (score 3):

You do this through Wordpress Settings, the index.php and .htaccess files.

1. **Go to the General Settings in your Admin area**. You will see that "WordPress Address" and "Site Address" fields will have the same URL. You need to change the **Site Address** option to point to your root domain, i.e. `http://www.nextarconsulting.com` and *leave WordPress Address option as it is*.
2. **Copy the `.htaccess` file** from the installation subfolder (i.e. SitoNextar) to the domain root folder
3. **Copy the site's `index.php` file** from the installation subfolder (i.e. SitoNextar) to the domain root folder, and edit it as follows:

Change this line in `index.php`:

```
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

to include the installation folder, e.g.:

```
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/SitoNextar/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

**Notes**:

You might also need to resave your permalinks after doing this.

You still **login** and use the Admin area from the installation folder (i.e. [www.nextarconsulting.com/SitoNextar/wp-admin](http://www.nextarconsulting.com/SitoNextar/wp-admin))

**Reference**: [How to Get Rid of /wordpress/ From your WordPress Site URL](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-get-rid-of-wordpress-from-your-wordpress-site-url/